# The compatibility constant

Tags: linear-algebra, regression-analysis, linear-regression

I am reading [Lecture notes on sparsity](https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2016/sparsity/sparsity-ETH.pdf) by Sara van de Geer and trying to understand the idea behind the compatibility constant.

Suppose that $\beta\in\mathbb R^p$. Let $S\subset\{1,\ldots,p\}$ be an index set and let us denote by $\beta_{S}$ a $p$-vector with entries equal to zero at the indexes $j\not\in S$, i.e. $\beta_{j,S}=\beta_j1\{j\in S\}$
for $j=1,\ldots,p$. $\beta_{-S}$ denotes the vector $\beta_{S^c}$. We have $\beta=\beta_S+\beta_{-S}$ for any vector $\beta\in\mathbb R^p$. The following definition is given in the notes (Subsection 1.6).

> For a constant $L>1$ and an index set $S\subset\{1,\ldots,p\}$, the *compatibility constant* is defined by
>   $$
>  \hat\phi^2(L,S)=\min\biggl\{\frac{|S|}n\|X\beta_S-X\beta_{-S}\|_2^2:\|\beta_S\|_1=1,\ \|\beta_{-S}\|_1\le L\biggr\},
> $$
>   where $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ is the design matrix, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $\ell_1$-norm.

It is written that this is a notion of compatibility between the $\ell_1$-norm and the Euclidean norm. However, I do not understand what this precisely means. What is idea behing the compability constant? How does this constant relate the $\ell_1$-norm to the Euclidean norm?

They claim that the inequality (inequality (1.11) in the notes)
$$
\|\hat\beta_S-\beta\|_1\le\frac{\sqrt{|S|}\|X(\hat\beta-\beta)\|_2}{n\hat\phi(L,S)}
$$
follows from the definition of the compatiblity constant, where $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ is the design matrix and $\hat\beta\in\mathbb R^p$ is the Lasso estimator. Could anyone provide some details how this inequality follows from the definition?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that it is $\beta$ and not $\beta_{S}$? At LHS of the claim.

Comment: @echzhen Yes, I double checked that. The same statement is proved in [these lecture notes](https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2016/sparsity/sparsity-ETH.pdf) (equation (1.11)).

Comment: Maybe at least the support of $\beta$ is equal to $S$?

Comment: @echzhen No, it does not seem so. $\beta$ is any vector in $\mathbb R^p$ as far as I understand. Inequality (1.11) is a part of a direct proof of Theorem 1.7.1 on p. 18 of the notes.

Comment: What about $S = S_{\beta}$ on top of p.18?

Comment: @echzhen This denotes the active set of the vector $\beta\in\mathbb R^p$, i.e. $S_\beta=\{j:\beta_j\ne0\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48886/discussion-between-echzhen-and-cm7f7bb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rewrite the definition of compatibility constant as it follows
$$
 \hat\phi^2(L,S)=\min\biggl\{\frac{|S|}n\|X\delta_S-X\delta_{-S}\|_2^2:\|\delta_S\|_1=1,\ \|\delta_{-S}\|_1\le L\biggr\}.
$$
Now, notice that we have
$$
\|\hat{\beta}_{-S} - \beta_{-S}\|_1 \leq L \|\hat{\beta}_{S} - \beta_{S}\|_1.
$$
Denote $\hat{\delta}_S =  \beta_{S} - \hat{\beta}_{S}$ and $\hat{\delta}_{-S} = \hat{\beta}_{-S} - \beta_{-S}$, therefore
$$
\|\hat{\delta}_{-S}\| \leq L \|\hat{\delta}_S\|_1.
$$
Introduce one more vector $\delta_S = \hat{\delta}_S / \|\hat{\delta}_S\|_1$ and $\delta_{-S} = \hat{\delta}_{-S} / \|\hat{\delta}_S\|_1$, we know

$$
\|\delta_{-S}\|_1 \leq L, \\
\|\delta_{S}\|_1 = 1,
$$
hence by definition of compatibility constant we have
$$
\hat\phi^2(L,S) \leq \frac{|S|}n\|X\delta_S-X\delta_{-S}\|_2^2 = \frac{|S|\|X\hat \delta_S-X\hat \delta_{-S}\|_2^2}{n\|\hat{\delta}_S\|_1^2},
$$
it is sufficient to notice that $\beta_{-S} = 0$ and $X\hat \delta_S-X\hat \delta_{-S} = X\beta_{S} - X\hat{\beta}_{S} - X\hat\beta_{-S} = X(\beta - \hat\beta)$

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1)! How do we know that $\|\hat{\beta}_{-S} - \beta_{-S}\|_1 \leq L \|\hat{\beta}_{S} - \beta_{S}\|_1$?

Comment: Since $S = S_{\beta} = \{j : \beta_j \neq 0\}$, we have $\beta = \beta_S$ and $\beta_{-S} = 0$

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Great! Best of luck :)